# Regarding directional derivatives

Tags: temperature, differentiation, calculus

we know directional derivatives are the rate of change of any given scalar field along the given direction, and it is also equal to scalar product of gradient of the field and the unit vector along given direction: directional derivative =$\nabla f \cdot \hat{n}$ where $\hat{n}$ is the unit vector.

from this formula we see that the rate of change is zero perpendicular to direction of max change.

suppose the temperature field of a room is given but it is not necessary that temperature is constant perpendicular to direction of maximum change. Also is there any condition on the field for this formula to work? (we could always choose a field that doesnt remain constant perpendicular to its max change, in that case how this formula will be valid).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. It would be great, if you could improve the style of your question. E.g. use capital letters at the beginning of a sentence. Try to reduce the length of your sentences, such that they are simpler to comprehend. Finally, you could use Mathjax to display formulae.

Comment: why is directional derivative zero perpendicular to max change(gradient) we could always choose a fn which is not constant perpendicular to its gradient then how this formula wil give us correct answer

Comment: No, you couldn't. Do you have an explicit counter-example? Because if the function is differentiable you aren't supposed to find any.

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you asking for a physical scenario that is not mathematically possible?

Comment: The directional derivative in advanced calculus and advanced physics doesn't use a unit vector.  It uses the tangent vector of a path.  I'm not addressing your question.  I'm just letting you know that the definition you gave will change if you continue studying math and physics.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Tangent vectors are typically unit vectors, so I think your distinction is somewhat misleading. The definition given by the OP is correct.

Comment: @AaronStevens Stevens, the tangent vector used in most situations is the derivative of position with respect to a path parameter. If the path is parameterized by arclength, then the tangent vector is of unit length. Mathematicians call that a unit speed parameterization. A typical example of a tangent vector is velocity. See:https://books.google.com/books?id=zAAuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=misner%20thorne%20wheeler&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q&f=false – Steven Thomas Hatton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field has a local maximum or minimum at the point, the rate of change is zero for all directions.

If it is not the case, we can find a direction of maximum increase, that is the gradient. The opposite direction will be of course the direction of maximum decrease.

It is not possible to rotate continuously between them, without pass by a direction of no change.

Answer (score 1):

> Also is there any condition on the field for this formula to work?

The field must be continuously differentiable.

> we could always choose a field that doesnt remain constant perpendicular to its max change, in that case how this formula will be valid.

This is not correct.  The fact that $\nabla f \cdot \hat{n}=0$ for $\hat{n}$ perpendicular to the gradient is the proof that it's not true.  This is a good discussion of the topic:

https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_02.html